# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException coming in this array using java?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array of numbers in Java and need to output the ones that consist of only duplicated digits. However, my code throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Where is the problem?

```
int[] inputValues= {122, 2, 22, 11, 234, 333, 000, 5555, 8, 9, 99};

for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
    int numberLength = Integer.toString(inputValues[i]).length();
//  System.out.println(numberLength);
    if (numberLength > 1) { //more than one digit in the number
        String s1 = Integer.toString(inputValues[i]);
        String[] numberDigits = s1.split("");

        for (int j = 1, k = 1; j < numberDigits.length; k++) {
            if (numberDigits[j].equals(numberDigits[k + 1])) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate values are:");
                //I need to print 22,11,333,000,5555,99 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: haven't all numbers `x > 9 || x < -9` more than one digit? There's no need to convert it into a String.

Comment: @dusky,to get desired output could you please edit my code.

Comment: @GangadharB see my answer below , if that suits

Comment: @ShubhangMalviya,please check 
Sujit Thombare answer,very simple one.but there is one error in his code.if array value are 10,20,30,333,999,then giving wrong output.

Comment: @GangadharB First for my answer you need to call getDuplicate(int[] arr) method and that all. It will return the correct answer. If you didn't understand my code , then plz comment.

Comment: Can anybody tell me why vote down for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {


    int[] inputValues={122,2,22,11,234,333,000,5555,8,9,99,1000};



    System.out.println("Duplicate values are:");
      for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {

          String strNumber = new Integer(inputValues[i]).toString();// get string from array

          if(strNumber.length()>1)  // string length must be greater than 1
          {

              Character firstchar =strNumber.charAt(0);  //get first char of string

              String strchker =strNumber.replaceAll(firstchar.toString(), ""); //repalce it with black



              if(strchker.length()==0)   // for duplicate values length must be 0
              {
                  System.out.println(strNumber);

              }

          }


       }


      /*
       * output will be 
       * Duplicate values are:
        22
        11
        333
        5555
        99
       * 
       * 
       */
}
```

This is what you want.....

Comment: ,if array having 10,20,30 then resulting is not correct.

Comment: Please give me your input array and tell me what output you want..... What exactly you want ?

Comment: ,input is int[] inputValues = {122,10,20,101,2, 22, 11, 234, 333, 5555, 8, 9, 99};
        output is:22,11,333,5555,99

Comment: ,code is working fine.for numbere 0000 output has to come in Duplicate value.It's not printing.Is it valid one or not.

Comment: if you working with int array then 0000 is consider as only 0 ....so it will not be coming in output.... if you want 0000 in output then go with String array.

Comment: ,Thank you for spending your valuable time.

Comment: ,i added these lines to print zero's else{
              int valueTemp = Integer.parseInt(strNumber);
                 if (valueTemp == 0) {
                    System.out.println(valueTemp);
                 }

Answer (score 3):

There is no condition to stop the inner loop when `k` gets too big.  `j` never changes in the inner loop, so `j < numberDigits.length` will either always be true or always be false.

Comment: David,to get desired output could you please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This line is the culprit here -

```
for (int j = 1, k = 1; j < numberDigits.length; k++) {
    if (numberDigits[j].equals(numberDigits[k + 1])) {
        System.out.println("Duplicate values are:");//i need to print 22,11,333,000,5555,99,etc.
    }
}
```

The loop has a condition that's always true as value of j is always 1. Since k keeps on increasing by 1 for each iteration ( which are infinite btw ), the index goes out of array bounds.

Try -

```
for (int j = 0, k = 1; k < numberDigits.length; k++) {
    boolean isDuplicate = true;
    if (!numberDigits[j].equals(numberDigits[k])) {
        isDuplicate = false;
        break;
    }
}
if( isDuplicate ) {
    System.out.println("Duplicate values are:"+inputValues[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for joining the party late. I think following is the piece of code you’re are looking for

```
private int[] getDuplicate(int[] arr) {
        ArrayList<Integer> duplicate = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int item : arr) {
            if(item > 9 && areDigitsSame(item)) {
                duplicate.add(item);
            }
        }

        int duplicateDigits[] = new int[duplicate.size()];

        int index = 0;
        for (Integer integer : duplicate) {
            duplicateDigits[index ++] = integer;
        }
        return duplicateDigits;
    }

    public boolean areDigitsSame(int item) {
        int num = item;
        int previousDigit = item % 10;
        while (num != 0) {
            int digit = num % 10;
            if (previousDigit != digit) {
                return false;
            }
            num /= 10;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Now , use it as below

```
int[]inputValues={122,2,22,11,234,333,000,5555,8,9,99};
int[] duplicates = getDuplicate(inputValues);
```

That's all

Enjoy!

Comment: I've added the usage , in case

Comment: Shubhang Malviya,Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GangadharB You're welcome :) but If you really like it , would you mind upvoting my answer.

Comment: Shubhang Malviya,i feel  comfort with
Sujit Thombare code (easy to understand).Sorry Shubhang Malviaya.

Comment: @GangadharB upvoting an answer and accepting an answer are two different things :) , upvoting means that either you gain knowledge from the answer or that can be an alternative answer , but accepting answer means that you want to go ahead with that answer , so plz don't mis understand my suggestion :)

Comment: @GangadharB also you can upvote many answers but you can accept only one

Comment: Shubhang Malviya,to upvote i need 15 reputations i have only 8 reputations.what should i do.

Comment: @GangadharB I have increased youre reputation to 18 , now's youre turn

Comment: @ Shubhang Malviya,i did

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void  main(String[] args) {


        String[] inputValues={"122","2","22","11","234","333","000","5555","8","9","99"};



        System.out.println("Duplicate values are:");
          for (int i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {

              String strNumber = inputValues[i];// get string from array
              if(strNumber.length()>1)  // string length must be greater than 1
              {
                  Character firstchar =strNumber.charAt(0);  //get first char of string

                  String strchker =strNumber.replaceAll(firstchar.toString(), "0"); //repalce it with 0

                if(Integer.parseInt(strchker)==0)   //if all values are duplictae than result string must be 0
                {
                  System.out.println(strNumber);
                }

              }


           }

    }
   // /// result will be
 /*  Duplicate values are:
   22 
   11
   333
   000
   5555
   99
*/
```

if you want int array then you will not able to get "000" as duplicate value.

Comment: Sujit Thombare ,thank you,output is ok ignore 000 i need int array values.could you please help me.

Comment: then replace 5th line with   ` String strNumber = new Integer(inputValues[i]).toString();`   and replace your String array with int array

Comment: Sujit Thombare ,if array having 10,20,30 values then output is wrong.please edit your code.

Comment: Please give me your input array and tell me what output you want..... What exactly you want ?

Comment: ,input: int[] inputValues = {122,10,20,101,2, 22, 11, 234, 333, 5555, 8, 9, 99};
        output is:22,11,333,5555,99

Answer (score 0):

@ line 13: the    **`s1.split("")`**      results to `[, 1, 2, 2]` for    122   . Hence your numberDigits.length is 4. The loop runs from j = 1 to 3 ( j < numberDigits.length); hence the `numberDigits[k + 1 ]` is evaluated for index 4 which is unavailable for `[, 1, 2, 2]`.

Another point is worth noting is int[]inputValues will always store 000 as 0 only.

The below mentioned method will take a integer number and will return true and false based on your requirement. It will use xor operator to check repetitive digits.

```
private static boolean exorEveryCharacter(int currentValue) {
        int result = 0;
        int previousNumber = -1;

        while (currentValue != 0) {
            int currentNumber = currentValue % 10;

            if(previousNumber == -1){
                previousNumber = currentNumber;
            }
            else{
                result = previousNumber ^ currentNumber;
            }

            currentValue /= 10;
        }
        return result == 0;
    }
```

Comment: @GangadharB: The above code uses a simple property that for any two same values there xor will return 0. So you just need to xor the individual elements of any number. If the final output is 0 then it had same digits. I think its very simple.

Feel free to ask any doubt.